# Directory Transversal and File Deletion

Tags: python, security

(Edit) My name is George and I'm currently trying to create a python script that can locate and delete certain files with the '.bak' or any file extension.

Here's my current progress:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


'''

directory transversal and deletion

'''

import os
 

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
    
        if file.endswith('.bak'):
            print(root+'/'+str(file))



# generate 2 batch files

def apples():
    
    # To Hunt down the file and then yeet itself



# copy batch file into target directory



# Successful deletion

print("Successful")
```

I took some of the code from geeksforgeek because I figured that if I can get the specific targets for where the files are I figured I would have an easier time deleting them.

Comment: what is stopping you from hunting them down? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but I might have an easier solution nonetheless for what I understand.

Path manipulation through the `os.path` module is annoying, and since Python 3.3, the `pathlib` module has been in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Since you're trying to find `.bak` files in the current directory, I think it's easier to do something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
dir_path = Path.cwd()
for file in dir_path.glob('**/*.bak'):
    print(file)
```

The question remains of what exactly you want to do with those files, and you might want to edit your question to explain that more clearly.

Hope this helped a bit :)